# Instagram oauth - error 400 matching code not found

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Problem started two days ago and affected about 70% of our users.
This error is not depends on IP, libraries or server configuration.

Instagram ignores my requests, Facebook do too.

I've tried to reset client secret, change IP and region, so nothing helped.

Other users reports same problem: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13178789

Maybe someone from Instagram/Facebook read StackOverflow and can give some advise or clarify this situation?

Comment: Having the same issue. Added my info to the "report an issue" on the instagram developer pages.

Comment: @kendepelchin we reported this issue twice, still no answer

Comment: add logs and make sure you are making only one POST call with oauth code to get `access_token`

Comment: @krisrak it was first i've done. I even tried to make requests in pure ipython shell

Comment: is direct curl working? (added my experience here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13194571)

Comment: @krisrak curl works sometimes, it's not a networking problem

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Instagram api has move `api.instagram.com` to `www.instagram.com` with a 302 redirect.

If you are using `omniauth-instagram` gem, you can use this fix:

```
#config/initializers/omniauth_instagram_api_path.rb

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Instagram
      option :client_options, {
        :site => 'https://www.instagram.com',
        :authorize_url => 'https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize',
        :token_url => 'https://www.instagram.com/oauth/access_token'
      }
    end
  end
end
```

The purpose is the replace `api.instagram.com` by `www.instagram.com`.

I managed to make my staging and production application work.

Comment: It still does not work for some users in my production environment. I have another work around:

Comment: - Step 1: Open a new tab and login in Instagram and keep this tab open
- Step 2: Open a new tab and go to your web application and login via Instagram.

I tested 10 times with my "invalid-credentials" account and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this consistently. After much investigation (a whole day), it appears that Instagram has changed their main API host for authentication from https://api.instagram.com to https://www.instagram.com and redirect with a 302.

If your code sends a POST to api.instagram.com it is redirected, and (I'm guessing here) Instagram counts that as two requests.

I've changed `api.instagram.com` in [my oauth code](https://github.com/stefl/omniauth-instagram/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/instagram.rb) to `www.instagram.com` and was able to get an access token.

Comment: This did not seem to help me unfortunately :/ And the error is very inconsistent. Signing out of Instagram before performing auth seems to help though.

Answer (score 0):

Also having this issue. If you login via the web to Instagram and then try the auth flow seems to be a work around.

Comment: Unfortunately, this workaround is not consistent.