# InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token using passportjs

Tags: oauth, instagram, passport.js

I am using https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2 as my library to authenticate via Instagram, and everything was working fine until this error spontaneously occurred 2 days ago with no explanation as to why it has failed to obtain the access token.

My client IDs and secrets are correct and my client app is live according to instagram/developers. Is there some known solution to this? I haven't changed my code since I got this error so it can't be on my side especially since the error seems to be from the library but that hasn't been updated in a while either.

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163518/instagram-oauth-error-400-matching-code-not-found